# Delete rows from 4 tables based on one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a query to delete all records from a user in the database. There is one table users:

```
user_id | name
```

one table posts

```
post_id | user_id | post_html
```

one table posts_tags

```
id | post_id | tag_id
```

one table tags

```
id | user_id | tag
```

I'm looking to delete all records linked to a user from this 4 tables...
Like

```
delete from tags t inner join posts_tags bt on t.id = bt.tag_id where ???
```

Thanks

Comment: Just perform 4 `DELETE` queries. That's it. It's perfectly fine to perform multiple queries, not a single one. Or use foreign keys with `CASCADE`

Comment: I have to do a query on table posts with a while to check all posts and then each time make 2 queries to delete from posts_tags and tags... This is not very clean, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one statement, if you like:

```
delete u, p, pt, t
    from users u join
         posts p
         on u.id = p.user_id join
         posts_tags pt 
         on p.id = pt.post_id join
         tags t
         on t.id = pt.tag_id
    where u.id = @YOURUSERID;
```

Comment: @RomanPekar . . . It is MySQL-specific.  I don't know if any other databases extend `delete` this way.  (Personally, I would generally use four queries, because I work with multiple different databases.)

Comment: Doesn't work: "0 lignes modified" when I put an existing user id... :-(

Comment: @user2670167 . . . This query makes the assumption that a user has appropriate records in all the tables.  That may not be true.

Comment: "That may not be true." --- and it makes the query pointless... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with zerkms - you could use cascade foreign keys. But it could be written as SQL queries too, but if you have foreign keys, you have to do it in correct order, something like:

```
delete from posts_tags
where
    tag_id in (select id from tags where user_id = <your user id>) or
    post_id in (select post_id from posts where user_id = <your user id>)

delete from tags
where user_id = <your user id>

delete from posts
where user_id = <your user id>

delete from users
where user_id = <your user id>
```